# Issues with quoted string regex in antlr4

Tags: antlr4

I want to parse strings like "TOM*", "TOM" , "*TOM" , "*TOM*", "*" and all these without quotes. I created 2 rules name_with_quotes & name without quotes, but string with quotes are giving expected token: <EOF> error

I have following tokens in lexer.g4 file

```
    ID : [a-zA-Z0-9-_]+ ;
    WILDCARD_STARTS_WITH_STRING: ID'*';
    WILDCARD_ENDS_WITH_STRING: '*'ID;
    WILDCARD_CONTAINS_STRING : '*'ID'*' ;
STRING : ('"' | '\'') ( ( (~('"' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n') | '\\'('"' ) )*) | ) ('"' | '\'');     
 QUOTED_ID : ('"' | '\'') (((STAR)? ID (STAR)?) | ID | STAR) ('"' | '\'');
```

I have following rules in my parser file:

```
name_without_quotes : ID | WILDCARD_STARTS_WITH_STRING | WILDCARD_ENDS_WITH_STRING | WILDCARD_CONTAINS_STRING | STAR  ;
name_with_quotes : QUOTED_ID;

name : name_with_quotes  | name_without_quotes;
```

I also tried using following rules.

```
WITHOUT_QUOTES : '"'  (ID | ID'*' | '*'ID | '*'ID'*' ) '"';
WITH_QUOTES : ID | WILDCARD_STARTS_WITH_STRING | WILDCARD_ENDS_WITH_STRING | WILDCARD_CONTAINS_STRING | STAR  ;
```

But no luck. Any clue what I could be doing wrong? 
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution here.
http://www.antlr3.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2012-March/044273.html.
Just changed the order and it worked.